# Tensorflow Convolution return Nan

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

I'm trying to read image from folder and perform convolution.

First, I input these images and package them as `.tfrecords`, and decode the tfrecords by `tf.train.batch`.
Next, I put all data(image,label) into convolution (as code).
In this step,the `bias`(b_conv1) and `weight`(w_conv1) will be *Nan*, and the model won't work any more.

```
image_batch, label_batch = decodeTFRecord(dirPath,batch_size)
image_batch = tf.reshape(image_batch,[-1,128*128])
label_batch = tf.one_hot(label_batch,Label_size)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,128*128])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
x_image = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.reshape(x,[-1,128,128,1]))
#conv1 layer
w_conv1 = weight_variable([5,5,1,32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image,w_conv1)+b_conv1) #outsize = 128*128*32
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1) # outsize = 64*64*32
```

**conv2d function:**

```
def conv2d(x,W):
   return tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding ='SAME')
```

**max_pool_2x2 function:**

```
def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x,ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')
```

Full Code: 
https://codeshare.io/5O7ddj

Comment: I'm confused, you have placeholders for your images so you can pass them in via `feed_dict`, but you also appear to be drawing them directly from TF records via a tensorflow reader that is not shown. I guess you're making 2 calls to `sess.run`, once to get the images and another to feed them back in via `feed_dict`? If so that's not optimal. But the most fundamental debugging question is whether the input to the model (your images) has NaNs, or whether the NaNs occur during the model computation. Check on this and update the question.

Comment: @DavidParks i reference this github, https://github.com/MorvanZhou/tutorials/blob/master/tensorflowTUT/tf18_CNN3/full_code.py
Before convolution, the bias and weight  will be float(not equal Nan). Once perform convolution (first loop), the bias and weight will get Nan,and the result form convolution will be 0.

Comment: Try a smaller learning rate to start with `1e-5` and make your initial weights smaller `tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev = 0.0001)` and see if either of those common issues fix your problem.

Comment: @DavidParks really thanks for you help, the bias and wieght won't be Nan any more. I'm trying to improve my model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a smaller learning rate to start with `1e-5` and make your initial weights smaller `tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev = 0.0001)` and see if either of those common issues fix your problem.

Based on comments it sounds like one of these two common issues caused the `NaN` problem (please comment if I misread your comment).

This issue often occurs when the weights are randomly initialized because large weights will have a long way to travel to improve, which can result in a very steep gradient step, e.g. the exploding gradient problem. Small weights/learning rates will ameliorate this issue.

Also notable is that BatchNorm will tend to ameliorate the problem as well. You can generally get away with much larger learning rates precisely because BatchNorm keeps things from getting really out of whack as the signal travels through the network.